# Using microsoft sync framework 2.1 for SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

We need to synchronize database and image files between two servers. The source server has sql server 2000 and the destination server has sql server 2008. We need to synchronize data in some tables in sql server 2000 so that the updated data comes to sql server 2008 every once in a while. Similarly for the folder where images are stored.

I tried to implement Microsoft sync framework (http://msdn.microsoft.com/sync) with WCF to achieve the goal. I ran the following project successfully for two databases in SQL Server 2008:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Database-SyncSQL-Server-e97d1208/sourcecode?fileId=19017&pathId=519811259

However, when I tried to synchronize data between database, one in sql server 2000 and sql server 2008, then I could not synchronize data.

Questions:

1. Is there anyway to synchronize data between sql server 2000 and sql server 2008?
2. If not, are there any other possible architectures i can implement to achieve the objective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the minimum Sql Server version for the sync provider in the sample you used above is Sql Server 2005 SP2 (where min_active_version() was introduced.)

try using the steps in this link so you can overrride the commands and make them work against Sql 2000: [Synchronizing Other ADO.NET Compatible Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc807291%28SQL.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the link. I tried to make the project work against SQL Server 2000 as show in the link. I manipulated min_active_version() in one of the stored procedures so that it won't give error. Everything works except when the code sampleSyncAgent.Synchronize() fires, i got the exception "Snapshot isolation transaction failed accessing database 'DBName' because snapshot isolation is not allowed in this database. Use ALTER DATABASE to allow snapshot isolation." As you know, i cannot use snapshot isolation in sql server 2000 (ALTER DATABASE [database name] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON).

Comment: i think you can get away not setting snapshot isolation. check out the Oracle provider sample here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Database-Sync-Oracle-and-037fb083. you can treat your custom provider similar to this.

Comment: Hi JuneT, I've already looked into Oracle provider example and converted in SQL Server 2000 version. It was painful to convert all the pl/sql script to sql server version and change the codes to make it compatible with sql server 2000, when, finally, the same error comes. The error is same in line 47 of SynchronizationHelper.cs (that is in: SyncOperationStatistics stats = orchestrator.Synchronize();).Have you tried it yourself? If yes, would be great, if u share me some knowledge.

Comment: have you replaced the SqlSyncProvider in the sample you used with your custom DbSyncProvider?

Comment: The sample is using custom Oracle provider "OracleDbSyncProvider" and I've replaced it with DbsyncProvider. The code runs until i press "Synchronize" button which triggers orchestrator.Synchronize() and i get this error "The System.Data.IsolationLevel enumeration value, Snapshot, is not supported by SQL Server 7.0 or SQL Server 2000."

Comment: in the sample oracle provider, you will find that it overrides the CreateEnumerationTransaction. try doing the same for your custom provider and override CreateEnumerationTransaction and CreateApplicationTransaction to specify a different transaction isolation level. also check that you are using your custom provider and not DbSyncProvider.

Comment: I created custom sql provider and override CreateEnumerationTransaction with the change:  new SqlCommand("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED", (SqlConnection)this.Connection, trans).ExecuteNonQuery();

Now, i get this popular error in orchestrator.Synchronize() :
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". How can I find out what's going on behind the scene, i mean in Synchronize event??. Shall i send you the project instead?